# Refer to cell B2 with text "B2"

Tags: excel, text

I have a text "B1" in a random cell of an excel sheet
Is there a way to make excel read out the text "B1" and convert it to the coordinate of the cell B1 and give me the value of B1?

Comment: Yes there is, can't remember the function name off-hand but you should really be consulting the online documentation for this type of question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `INDIRECT` function like this:

`=INDIRECT(A1)`

Now just replace `A1` with the cell that contains the text "B1".

Comment: Note for OP: Beware that `INDIRECT` is volatile.

Comment: That's it. Great! Thank you!

Comment: @JvdV Good point, having a lot of `INDIRECT`s in your workbook can slow down your workbook immensely.

Comment: @burazija If this answer solved your problem, please, mark it as correct, so it can be closed.